# Authentication failure: JDBC Realm in JBoss EAP 6.1

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jboss

I've set up a JDBC realm in JBoss to handle user authentication/authorisation in a web app. I'm not receiving any error messages but authorisation fails with both of the test users and I'm struggling to understand why.

The project has been the result of pulling together forum posts on JDBC Security Realms on both JBoss and Tomcat so its entirely possible I've missed something but I can't see the wood for the trees anymore.

Relevant sections from Standalone.xml (JBoss management console shows DB connection & pool is OK so I know the driver is installed correctly):

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/securitytest</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <driver>com.mysql</driver>
    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>jboss_as</user-name>
        <password>test</password>
    </security>
    <statement>
        <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
        <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
</datasource>
<drivers>
    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
    <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
</drivers>
....
<security-domain name="JDBCRealm" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/MysqlDS"/>
            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select user_password from USERS where user_name=?"/>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select role_name, 'Roles' from  ROLES where user_name=?"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

MySQL test database (securitytest) contains two tables (users - three columns ID, user_name, password and roles - three columns: ID, user_name, role_name, group_name) and I have populated these with "user" and "admin" both with "password" as the password. Role_name and group_name are set to the name of the respective users. Entries are cleartext (currently)

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<!-- Roles -->
<security-role>
    <description>Administrators</description>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <description>Management</description>
    <role-name>mgmt</role-name>
</security-role>

<!--  Resource/role mapping -->
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Admin Pages</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Admin Area</web-resource-name>
        <description />
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>For administrators only</description>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>All Access</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Unprotected User Area</web-resource-name>
        <description>Open access for all users</description>
        <url-pattern>/users/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<!-- Login prompt -->
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>JDBCRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginerror.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
</web-app>
```

jboss.xml (in WEB-INF directory):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/JDBCRealm</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

Finally, login.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
<title>Login Form</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<p:panel header="Login From">
<form method="post" action="j_security_check">
Username: <input type="text" name="j_username" />
Password: <input type="password" name="j_password" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form> 

</p:panel>
</h:body>
</html>
```

If anyone has any ideas I'd be really grateful as I'm tearing my hair out. I'm sure I've done something stupid, I just can't see it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be help you for configuring it in the right way.

http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=2187